# How to force showing the popup part of a ComboBox in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, combobox, controls

I want to be able to always show the popup part of a combobox regardless of the fact it has been clicked or not, or even without the combo being focused. I tried to use the `show()` method of the combo, but in my case the popup part never shows.

My code is:

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComBoBoxTest {
   public static final void main(String[] args) {
      ComBoBoxTest test = new ComBoBoxTest();
      test.setup();
   }

   private void setup() {
      new JFXPanel();
      Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            createUI();
         }

      });
   }

   private void createUI() {
      Stage stage = new Stage();
      Pane pane = new Pane();
      ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox();
      ObservableList<String> values = combo.getItems();
      values.add("ONE");
      values.add("TWO");
      values.add("THREE"); 
      combo.setVisibleRowCount(3);
      combo.show();
      pane.getChildren().add(combo);
      Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show(); // the important part
   }
}
```

In that case, I thought that my `show()` method would force to open the popup, but the result is that the popup is never shown

Comment: try to show after the scene is showing .. there had been (or still is?) a bug that didn't sync the skin state to the combo state. Anyway, what is this weird setup? Why not extend and use Application to fire up the fx thread?

Comment: It works thanks. However this setup was just for the sake of having a reproductible example quickly. I agree that it might be look weird

Comment: "_However this setup was just for the sake of having a reproductible example quickly_" – It's quicker and more straightforward to use the standard JavaFX lifecycle when creating minimal examples which only involve JavaFX (not e.g., Swing). For instance, your example now requires the `javafx.swing` module, which if you had simply extended `Application` and overridden the `start(Stage)` method, would otherwise not be needed. Also, you don't even need a main method when extending `Application`. And finally, it's just easier for people to follow when you use the standard setup.

Comment: But if you really for some reason don't want to extend `Application`, then there's no reason to use `JFXPanel` these days (unless you're integrating with Swing). Just use `Patform#startup(Runnable)`, which was added in JavaFX 9.

Comment: In the initial app, the JavaFX content was created from Swing. However, I will update the example (with JavaFX 8, because kleopatra remarked that the initial problem was fixed in JFX 17) with pure JavaFX for the sake of clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the excellent comment of kleopatra, the solution is to call `show()` on the Combo **after** the Stage is shown. This example works:

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComBoBoxTest {
   public static final void main(String[] args) {
      ComBoBoxTest test = new ComBoBoxTest();
      test.setup();
   }

   private void setup() {
      new JFXPanel();
      Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            createUI();
         }

      });
   }

   private void createUI() {
      Stage stage = new Stage();
      Pane pane = new Pane();
      ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox();
      ObservableList<String> values = combo.getItems();
      values.add("ONE");
      values.add("TWO");
      values.add("THREE"); 
      combo.setVisibleRowCount(3);
      
      pane.getChildren().add(combo);
      Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show(); 
      combo.show(); // call show() on the Combo after the stage is shown
   }
}
```

Comment: a couple of notes: a) the broken initial sync (between combo.isShowing and the popup actually visible after adding to the scene) is fixed in fx17 which means: 1) with the normal application startup (extending application, do stuff in start) the popup is showing under the combo as expected 2) with the manual firing up of the fx thread as done here, the popup is also showing but at the upper leading corner of the screen. So the issue could be resolved by updating the fx version _and_ use the normal startup :)

Comment: I did not know that this was fixed in JavaFX 17, thanks!